# Does the name on this record say Nikiefor?

Tags: palaeography

I found a strange name on a [baptismal record](https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.3.1/TH-1942-22509-26563-63?cc=1910265&wc=M993-6L7:542752451) from Biały Kamień which is now part of Ukraine. The records are mostly in Polish and Latin.

[image]

It looks like "Nikiefor" but that's a very strange name. I've never seen that name before and I've viewed decades worth of records for the town. Plus there are only [169 results for it on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=nikiefor).

Extra points if you can tell me what the origin of the name is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reading of this given name as "Nikiefor" seems to be reasonable. [Behind the Name lists Nikifor](http://www.behindthename.com/name/nikifor) (without an "e") as the Russian, Bulgarian, Macedonian and Polish form of the Greek name [Nikephoros](http://www.behindthename.com/name/nikephoros).

Note 1: the full image of the register page, which would show additional examples of writing, is only viewable at a Family History Center or to LDS church members. See the collection description [Ukraine, Western Ukraine Catholic Church Book Duplicates](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Ukraine,_Western_Ukraine_Catholic_Church_Book_Duplicates_%28FamilySearch_Historical_Records%29) .

Note 2: many of the Google hits using "Nikiefor" spelling are error pages of various kinds. "Nikifor" has more than 3 million hits.